# How do I turn list of strings to list of ObjectIds in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, objectid

I'm using mongoose and I have the following list:

```
const ids: ["63bd7878f1f085f7d8a6827f", "63be730bf1f085f7d8a682c8"];
```

I want to turn `ids` into a list of ObjectIds..

I've tried the following:

```
const affectedUsers = await Users.find(
            { _id: { $in: [ids.map(e => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(e))] } }
        );
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[\n  new 
ObjectId(\"63bd7878f1f085f7d8a6827f\"),\n  new
ObjectId(\"63be730bf1f085f7d8a682c8\")\n]\" 
(type Array) at path \"_id\" for model \"users\""
```

Comment: `[ids.map(e => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(e))]` -> `ids.map(e => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(e))` because `.map()` returns an array, you don't need to wrap it in another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added extra brackets at `$in` query, try this...

```js
const affectedUsers = await Users.find(
  { _id: { $in: ids.map(e => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(e)) } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the extra array in the `$in` operator, like so:

```
const affectedUsers = await Users.find(
   { _id: { $in: ids.map(e => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(e)) } });
```